# InitializeComponent não existe no atual contexto

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xaml

Tenho esse código, onde eu tenho o erro

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AprovarPopup : PopupPage
    {
        public AprovarPopup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        // Method for animation child in PopupPage
        // Invoced after custom animation end
        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEnd()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(0.5);
        }

        // Method for animation child in PopupPage
        // Invoked before custom animation begin
        protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationBegin()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(1);
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            // Prevent hide popup
            //return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }

        // Invoced when background is clicked
        protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
        {
            // Return default value - CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked
            return base.OnBackgroundClicked();
        }
    }
```

e esse é meu xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="Demo.Pages.AprovarPopup">
    <!--Animations use example-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
      PositionIn="Center"
      PositionOut="Center"
      ScaleIn="1.2"
      ScaleOut="0.8"
      DurationIn="400"
      DurationOut="300"
      EasingIn="SinOut"
      EasingOut="SinIn"
      HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!-- Content -->
</pages:PopupPage>
```

nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853898/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-cannot-get) há a provável resposta, mas não entendi a questão do "Build Action" e também se o meu **x:Class** está correto.

**EDIT1**

Alterei o "build action" tanto do ***xaml*** quanto do ***xaml.cs*** e troquei para ***Page***, saiu o erro de **InitializeComponent**, mas disparou esse:

> A ação de compilação 'Page' não possui suporte pela combinação
>   específica de destinos do
>   projeto.  Autorizador C:\Labs\Autorizador\Autorizador\Autorizador\AprovarPopup.xaml   0

**EDIT2**

Resolvi com um Clean e Recompile. Tenho observado nesses meus poucos meses com a ferramenta **Xamarin.Forms** muita coisa resolvi com Clean e Recompile. Vi que limpeza é quase tudo, eheheh. Já está resolvido o problema. Vou deixar assim, prometi que quando eu fizesse um post e logo em seguida a solução, não iria responder, para não pensar que estou tentando "fraudar". Fica como Edição.

Answer (score 0):

Feche o visual studio e o emulador, vá em C:\Users\SEU_USUARIO\AppData\Local e remova a pasta xamarin, abra o visual studio novamente e seu app irá compilar normalmente